# Axios Request Failure In React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

Im not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I want the `Main` component to pass in the ajax request method to child component `InputForm`, which would return the results which would be stored in the `Main` component state.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ){
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            fetching : false,
            repos : {}
        };
        this.getGitHubRepo = this.getGitHubRepo.bind( this );
    }
    getGitHubRepo( user ){
        this.setState({ fetching : true });
        console.log( "form submitted!", user );
        axios.get( user )
            .then(( response ) => {
                console.log( "response =>", response );
            })
            .catch(( error ) => {
                console.log( "error => ", error );
            });
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className = "appContainer">
                <InputForm getGitHubRepo = { this.getGitHubRepo } />
            </div>
        );
    }
}



class InputForm extends React.Component{
    constructor( props ){
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            inputValue : "",
        };
        this.recordInput = this.recordInput.bind( this );
    }
    recordInput( e ){
        this.setState({ inputValue : e.target.value });
    }
    render(){
        let getPath = `https://api.github.com/${this.state.inputValue}`;
        return(
            <form onSubmit = {() => this.props.getGitHubRepo( getPath )}>
                <label htmlFor = "user_input">
                    Github Username
                </label>
                <input id = "user_input"
                         type = "input"
                         onChange = { this.recordInput } />
                <input type = "submit" value = "get repos" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render( <Main />, document.getElementById( "app" ));
```

[Here is the jsbin link.](https://jsbin.com/fuxevipine/edit?js,output)

I dont get any results & my webpack server refreshes the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you are not calling preventDefault on the form submission. 
Also, the url to get github repos was wrong, but that is secondary.

Check the updated jsbin: https://jsbin.com/sujakexamo/1/edit?js,output

```
class InputForm extends React.Component{
    constructor( props ){
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            inputValue : "",
        };
        this.recordInput = this.recordInput.bind( this );
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    recordInput( e ){
        this.setState({ inputValue : e.target.value });
    }

    submit (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.getGitHubRepo( `https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.inputValue}/repos` );
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit = {this.submit}>
                <label htmlFor = "user_input">
                    Github Username
                </label>
                <input id = "user_input"
                         type = "input"
                         onChange = { this.recordInput } />
                <input type = "submit" value = "get repos" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Canastro. I didn't realise the preventDefault.